# Как запустить программу прямиком из памяти?

Tags: c++, windows, pe

Хочу защитить свою программу на C++ паролем, вывел следующий алгоритм для этого:

1. Оригинальная программа хранится в статическом массиве в зашифрованном виде.
2. Вводим ключ от программы.
3. Оригинальная программа дешифруется.
4. Проверяется соответствие поля `e_magic` числу `0x5A4D` в `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` (MZ).
5. Вычисляется смещение для точки входа через `OptionalHeader`.
6. Вызывается точка входа оригинальной программы.

Как это выглядит в коде:

```
typedef int( *ProcessEntry_t )( int, char**, char** );
typedef unsigned __int64 QWORD, *QWORD_PTR, *PQWORD;

struct Binary
{
    Binary( Byte *Buffer, QWORD Size ) : Buffer( Buffer ), Size( Size ) {}

    Byte *Buffer;
    QWORD Size;
};

int main( int argc, char** argv, char** envp ) {
    printf( "Enter the password: " );
    std::string pass;
    std::cin>>pass;
    Binary binary = { rawData, sizeof rawData }; // rawData это массив байт с оригинальной программой в зашифрованном виде, он объявлен в другом файле
    Crypt crypt( &binary, new Key( pass ) );
    Binary *decryptedBinary = crypt.Decrypt( );
    if( !decryptedBinary ) { // Если в начале файла нет MZ (magic number), значит пароль неверный
        printf( "Wrong password!\n" );
        system( "pause" );
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        LPVOID lpTextPage = VirtualAlloc( 0, decryptedBinary->Size, MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE ); // выделяем память для запуска оригинальной программы
        memcpy( lpTextPage, decryptedBinary->Buffer, decryptedBinary->Size ); // записываем код оригинальной программы 
        BYTE *pBase = reinterpret_cast< BYTE * >( lpTextPage ); // =)
        auto *pOpt = &reinterpret_cast< IMAGE_NT_HEADERS * >( pBase+reinterpret_cast< IMAGE_DOS_HEADER * >( ( std::uintptr_t ) pBase )->e_magic )->OptionalHeader; // получаем OptionalHeader
        return reinterpret_cast< ProcessEntry_t >( pBase+pOpt->AddressOfEntryPoint )( argc, argv, envp ); // вычисляем смещение для точки входа и вызываем
    }
}
```

На практике мы ловим `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`. В ходе отладки я заметил, что вес оригинальной программы равен `61440` байт, а вот поле `AddressOfEntryPoint` (смещение до точки входа) равно `0x11262` (`70242`), то есть выходит за границы выделенной памяти. Я попробовал запустить оригинальную программу в x64dbg, и дошел до брикпоинта на точке входа. Смещение оказалось верным, но оно указывает на точку входа, только если запустить программу как обычно. Да, я знаю, что можно сделать дамп до точки входа и уже пробовать заводить его (дамп). Но в таком случае вес будет больше и придется мучиться с адресами и импортами, а мне этого не надо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как реализовать мою идею правильно?

Comment: Вы понимаете, что помимо вызова точки входа надо выполнить массу разных действий? Даже в DOS так можно было — и то создав корректный PSP — запустить .com-файл, но не .exe, для которого уже требуется дополнительная настройка таблицы адресов. Для Windows все еще страшнее :) A propos, гляньте: https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/32468/

Comment: Я так делал для динамических библиотек, там нужно было просто записать DLL в память, записать шелл-код который найдет DllMain по тем же NT-заголовкам и останется только вызвать её.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: @tobyaddroc, раз у вас получилось с dll, то что мешает повторить это, положив основные функции вашей программы в такую вот зашифрованную dll?